# Counting/summarizing values using filtered table in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to count/summarize a value in a filtered excel table and subdivide that count based on another parameter (without using macro/VBA)? For example one grocery store can sell multiple items. I want to filter by the store, and then summarize the result based on the item. The image below shows my current formula, it does't work as described (it summarizes the entire items column). I want it to show count for apples as 3 and average price 1.75. If I apply filter to only show Mike's Grocery items, then the count should be 1 and average price 2.25.

[image]

Comment: AGGREGATE or SUBTOTAL should do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtotal does not include any criteria for your conditions, and building this with formulas is a bit unwieldy and possibly overkill.

Consider using a Pivot table for your results table and use pivot table filters or slicers instead of filtering the source data.

[image]

If you want to use the Subtotal approach, take a look at https://exceljet.net/formula/count-visible-rows-only-with-criteria

Comment: Thanks very much, very helpful! Is there a way to prevent the items from being repeated for the two different stores in the Pivot Table? I just want apples to appear once, not to be repeated for every store.

Comment: What do you mean with "being repeated"? Pivot table columns are a hierarchy. If you drag the store into the row area, then the item underneath, you are creating a hierarchy of Store > Item. Each store will have a list of their items. That's how pivot tables work. But as you can see in my example, you don't need the store in the pivot table itself. You can just use it in the slicer, then each item is listed only once.